# Sort across multiple columns at the same time in javascript including different direction and sort types

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've seen many posts on sorting and even some on sorting on multiple columns.  They all seem to have intimate knowledge of the number of columns and their names, sort type and direction.

I need to:

- Have a sort routine that is generic and does not know any column names or other sort criteria until it's called.
- It needs to sort across ALL the columns in the criteria together at the same time.

The criteria might look like the following:

```
[
  {key: 'Employee', type: 'alpha', dir: 'asc'}, 
  {key: 'ProjectCode', type: 'numeric', dir: 'desc'}, 
  {key: 'WorkDate', type: 'date', dir: 'desc'}
]
```

Test data:

```
data = [
    {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 4574, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/6/18'},  
    {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'}
];
```

Resulting data:

```
[
    {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'},
    {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 4574, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/6/18'},  
    {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'}
]
```

So how to build a sort routine that can use such criteria and sort across ALL the criteria keys at one time?  Meaning duplicate employees would be sorted together and within them duplicate project codes sorted together and within them the duplicate dates.

Comment: Help me to help you, can you share what you have so far.

Comment: Ele, I posted my own answer at the same time I posted a question as it was a rework of a previous question I asked and in the meantime I came up with something. However, Patrick and Nina's answers are much more clever than mine.

Comment: Oops I didn't realize that!

Comment: @JoelCool I didn't downvote, but the people who did probably either didn't realize this was a self-answered question, or they did know and thought this was too trivial a use-case to provide a self-answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a fairly straightforward function that returns a scoped function you can pass to `Array.prototype.sort()`:

```js
function sortBy (criteria) {
  const sign = { asc: 1, desc: -1 };
  const sort = {
    numeric: (a, b) => a - b,
    date: (a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b),
    alpha: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)
  };
  
  const compare = criteria.map(
    ({ key, type, dir }) => (a, b) => sign[dir] * sort[type](a[key], b[key])
  );

  return (a, b) => compare.reduce((result, fn) => result || fn(a, b), 0);
}

let criteria = [
  {key: 'Employee', type: 'alpha', dir: 'asc'}, 
  {key: 'ProjectCode', type: 'numeric', dir: 'desc'}, 
  {key: 'WorkDate', type: 'date', dir: 'desc'}
];
let data = [
  {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
  {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'},  
  {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},
  {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 4574, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
  {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/6/18'},  
  {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'}
];

console.log(data.sort(sortBy(criteria)));
```

**Note:** As [Nina's answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48672882/1541563), `reduce()` iterates the entire `criteria` array while `some()` halts iteration at the first non-zero value, but the `result || fn(...)` at least short-circuits the comparison invocation within each iteration, so there aren't unnecessary criterion comparisons being evaluated.

If you've got a common sorting criteria, you can also have a reusable function for your sorting method:

```
const sortByMyCriteria = sortBy(criteria);

arrayA.sort(sortByMyCriteria);
arrayB.sort(sortByMyCriteria);
...
```

#### ES5 rewrite of `sortBy()` method:

```
function sortBy (criteria) {
  var sign = { asc: 1, desc: -1 };
  var sort = {
    numeric: function (a, b) { return a - b; },
    date: function (a, b) { return new Date(a) - new Date(b); },
    alpha: function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b); }
  };

  var compare = criteria.map(function (c) {
    var key = c.key, type = c.type, dir = c.dir;

    return function (a, b) {
      return sign[dir] * sort[type](a[key], b[key]);
    };
  });

  return function (a, b) {
    return compare.reduce(function (result, fn) {
      return result || fn(a, b);
    }, 0);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick!  Like Nina's answer I'll need to study it until I understand clearly.  You beat Nina by just several minutes.  :-)

Comment: @JoelCool would you like me to add an explanation to my answer? I can go into detail but I'll need to do it tonight.

Comment: I'm getting it a bit after reading about .some and .reduce.  Nina's is a little clearer to me probably just because I'm not too familiar with ES6 syntax yet.  It appears both solutions boil down to returning the appropriate -1, 1 or 0.  You have obviously answered the question. If you feel others would benefit from an explanation, I certainly would.  Specifically the criteria.map and compare.reduce.

Answer (score 1):

You could define some simple function for compare two values and store them in an object for an access via `type` property of the sortCriteria objects.

Then take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and use the sort result as return value. This method iterates until the end of the array or if the return value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), which is the value we need as return value for the sorting callback. Inside of the `some` callback the direction is used together with the function for retuning a relative value with two parameters for the function.

```js
var data = [{ Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18' }, { Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18' }, { Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18' }, { Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 4574, WorkDate: '1/5/18' }, { Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/6/18' }, { Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18' }],
    sortFn = {
        alpha: function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b); },
        numeric: function (a, b) { return a - b; },
        date: function (a, b) { return new Date(a) - new Date(b); }
    },
    sortCriteria = [{ key: 'Employee', type: 'alpha', dir: 'asc' }, { key: 'ProjectCode', type: 'numeric', dir: 'desc' }, { key: 'WorkDate', type: 'date', dir: 'desc' }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var value = 0;
    return sortCriteria.some(function (o) {
        return value = (o.dir === 'asc' || -1) * sortFn[o.type](a[o.key], b[o.key]);
    }) && value;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Looks like we had a lot of overlap with our approaches. Was yours an "improvement" of mine or did you just take a while to write this yourself?

Comment: `some` with short circuit vs `reduce` without.

Comment: It wasn't an accusation or anything, I see that you used `some`. I just noticed particularly your use of `sortFn` object, which wasn't present in the first posted answer.

Comment: Thanks Nina!  I don't completely understand it yet so I'll have to study it.  Any idea why I'm downvoted?

Comment: @NinaScholz I added a note in my answer to clarify at what level short-circuiting occurs in each answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using some ideas from other posts I came up with the following code that seems to work fine and returns the array in the correct order.

```js
data = [
 {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
 {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'},  
 {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},
 {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 4574, WorkDate: '1/5/18'},  
 {Employee: 'John Doe', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/6/18'},  
 {Employee: 'Harry Smith', ProjectCode: 3443, WorkDate: '1/7/18'}
];
sortCriteria = [
  {key: 'Employee', type: 'alpha', dir: 'asc'}, 
  {key: 'ProjectCode', type: 'numeric', dir: 'desc'}, 
  {key: 'WorkDate', type: 'date', dir: 'desc'}
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
 var x, y, i;
  
 for (i=0; i < sortCriteria.length; i++) {
   x = a[sortCriteria[i].key];
    y = b[sortCriteria[i].key];
    
  if (sortCriteria[i].type === 'date') {
     x = new Date(x).getTime();
      y = new Date(y).getTime();
    }
    if (sortCriteria[i].type === 'numeric') {
     x = parseFloat(x);
      y = parseFloat(y);
    }
    
  if (sortCriteria[i].dir === 'asc') {
      if (x < y) return -1;
      if (x > y) return 1;
    } else {
      if (x > y) return -1;
      if (x < y) return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(data);
```